# Python print not working with codecs

Tags: python, unicode, stdout, codec

I keep running into errors with unicode while printing things from wikipedia out in my console. I found a solution (that doesnt make my console crash when trying to use weird characters like Ł) and the solution was putting this at the top of my main file:

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout.buffer)
```

the thing is now my console doesn't print anything. Only when I cancel my code from running midway through does it show me what it was printing. It used to update in realtime (before I put the above code snippet in) as it pulled info from wikipedia. Can anyone explain how to fix this or an alternative solution.

To clarify: The error I would receive WITHOUT the above snippet of code was:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0141' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>
```

now with the code snippet it won't print anything in realtime but it DOES prevent that error. When the program finally finishes it will print everything out all at once-- but I want it to print as it is going(as it did before). I am using Python 3.6.5

Comment: Before I didn't have that code snippet at the top... now it doesnt print anything but it stops my program from crashing.

Comment: I am using Python version 3.6.5

Comment: I got: "AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute 'buffer'"

Answer (score 1):

`sys.stdout` is a buffered stream, that is, output is stored in the stream and not output until the buffer is *flushed*.

The `print` function will flush its output stream automatically, but if you are writing to the stream directly (for example, `sys.stdout.write('foo')`) you need to call its `flush()` explicitly to send output to the console.

If `sys.stdout` is not flushed while a program is executing, it will be flushed automatically when the programme is terminated, as described in the question.